# Getting the geometric boundary of state of Telangana in India in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-maps, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to use Google Earth Engine to get the geometry of the state of Telangana situated in the country of India. From the datasets available, the only dataset which has states clearly demarcated is the FAO GAUL: Global Administrative Unit Layers 2015, Second-Level Administrative Units feature collection. The latest data in this feature collection was in the year 2015.

Also, there is no state of Telangana in the dataset available, just the state of Andhra Pradesh.

Is there any way to get the geometric borders for the state of Telangana in Google Earth Engine?